# Ceiling drywall repair

Tags: drywall, repair, ceiling, patching-drywall

I have 2 sections in the drywall ceiling in my aunts bathroom I need to repair I’m not sure what they tried but it doesn’t look right and she wants me to fix it what should I know or how should I do it and what tools and materials will I need to fix it correctly and make it look like new [image]

Comment: Someone applied texturing to the old ceiling. That can be a Pain In The Arse to match  convincingly...

Comment: Is that an access hatch to the attic, or a square patch?

Comment: You seem to be asking for a complete drywall finishing primer. That's too broad a scope for this site (and there are many drywall patch questions already). I suggest you do some reading and come back with a more specific question.

Comment: That’s the ceiling in the bathroom room I guess my uncle tried to fix it and didn’t do a  good job - cheery

Comment: @Cheery I meant to tag u

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Remove that tape and patch the gap.

The get this product.

[image: patch]

[image: patch 1]

Comment: This is little more than a product recommendation. There's a whole heap of steps that come before that you've glossed right over.

Comment: Ok thank u so being I have never done this before I should like u say remove the tape then YouTube how to patch drywall then get that spray u jus showed ??

Comment: Remove tape, youtube, but buy the right product: you want ceiling (not wall) texture, possibly popcorn.